# I accidentally created a huge amount of files on my Desktop with Python. How do I get rid of them?

Tags: python, windows, loops

Hello so I accidentally run a python program which is very dangerous what I made. A create a loop and created millions of files on my Desktop with it. Damn what have I done! I cant even use my desktop now. screenshot: https://ibb.co/kq3VThv. Please do you know how do I fix this?
The code was:

```
import os


desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')

i = 1

while True:
    new_folder = 'Test'+str(i)
    folder_path = os.path.join(desktop, new_folder)
    with open(f"{folder_path}.bin",mode="a") as f:
       f.write("")
       f.close()
    i += 1
```

Comment: Even though you did this with Python, it seems like this is just a general computer question. You _might_ be more likely to get help from [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Basically though I think you just need to open your Desktop in File Explorer, switch to the details view, sort by date modified, and just select and delete all the files you just made. Seems pretty straightforward. Could also just search for `*.bin` and delete all of those if you don't have any real `.bin` files on your Desktop that you want to keep.

Comment: If you're sure you don't have any `.bin` files on your desktop you'd want to keep, just open a command prompt, `cd` to your Desktop folder, and `del Test*.bin`.

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by running this command in cmd:

del *.bin

Comment: This is possibly dangerous without context. I think at a minimum you should provide a more specific path, in your case `del ~/Desktop/*.bin`

Comment: Terrible idea. At least do above, or del Test*.bin